# How can I run an Angular app (for example) on any other place that's not localhost

Tags: angular, deployment, web-applications, webserver

I have had this question for quite a while now. If I develop a simple SPA on Angular and want to make it possible for other people to access it on other computers how can I do it?

Please let me know if I was not clear enough or if my english was not great.

Comment: Any hosting service that can serve a web page, can serve an Angular page. The issue is connections to a database and other backend services.

Comment: + 1 Adding to @georgeawg answer, I believe you would simply need to create a build before publishing to the online hosting service. The DB (if exists) would be a problem though as mentioned above, if it's on local.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks. In case I had a local DB that I just needed to get a cloud service that supported it like Azure, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deploy your app on a server. You have to build the app and get the files from dist folder and upload them to your server. You can read more about this [here](https://angular.io/start/start-deployment)

Use the Angular CLI and issue the

```
ng build
```

command in the root directory of your project. The site will be created in the dist directory and you can deploy that to any web server.

This will build for test, if you have production settings in your app you should use

```
ng build --prod
```

This will build the project in the dist directory and this can be pushed to the server.

Comment: thanks, I knew it had smoething to do with a service like Azure or in this case Firebase, I wasn't sure this was the best/only solution for this problem. Your answer was very helpful, thanks!